# Equal elements in a Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Today I had Interview where I was asked one problem, and I couldnt even understand.

Problem:

> Given one `array`  consisting of  integers.
>
> Get at least  equal elements in the `array` .
>
> While calculating, you can do below two operations
>
> - Take one of the minimum elements of the array and increase its value by one (more formally, if the minimum value of  is  then you choose such index  that = and set :=+1);
> - take one of the maximum elements of the array and decrease its value by one (more formally, if the maximum value of  is  then you choose such index  that = and set :=−1).
>
> Calculate the minimum number of moves required to obtain at least  equal elements in the array.

Can anyone help me to undestand, what's a actual problem is about so that I could write code ?

Comment: Uhm, have you tried something? Like even the smallest snippet of code?

Comment: "Can anyone help me to undestand" what do you understand, what don't you understand?

Comment: @First I need to understand the problem ..am not cleared with the problem itself !

Comment: Ok, but what is exactly you don't understand? You have an array and you're only allowed to perform those operations. Calculate the minimum operations required to get to k.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I need to calculate all elements in array having similar values but with min number of moves.  Is it correct  ? I didnt get the two conditions which are required to do this, mentioned in question.

Comment: @AndyTurner, One more thing is, How would code know, its calculating min number of moves ?

Comment: You basically can only manipulate the maximum and minimum values, for example: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, you can only increase 1 to 2 OR decrease 6 to 5

Comment: @B.Mik, What are  maximum and minimum values ?

Comment: The maximum integer value in your integer array and vice versa.

Comment: I have seen such questions getting closed in a jiffy! something is different here :-)

Comment: @Kris It is mainly because OP is asking what this means rather than asking for a solution (see answer by Sebastian which only explains the task and not how to solve it).

Comment: may be .. yeah!

Comment: By the way: One possible, but bad performing, solution is of course brute-force. You can just try out all possibilities (increase, increase vs increase, decrease vs decrease, increase vs decrease, decrease and so on). If you expand it like that then the first solution you find is actually also the best. An upper bound is always the sum of all values. As you can just stupidly decrease until all values are, for example `0`. E.g. `[1, 5, 3]` decrease 1+5+3=9 times and you have `[0, 0, 0]` which is a trivial solution. Obviously you can easily find tighter bounds but thats not the task anyways.

Comment: I'd look at sorting the list and iterating over a `k`-sized window, looking at the current average.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question directly, which is "Help me understand the problem":

For example, here's your array:

```
{1,2,5,7,8,3}
```

Now, you can do only those two operations:

1. Find the minimum element and increase it:

```
{2,2,5,7,8,3} // <-- increased 1
```

2. Decrease the maximum element:

```
{2,2,5,7,7,3} // <-- decreased 8
```

And the question now is: What is the minimum number of moves to make this array contain `k` identical numbers?

---

So if `k = 3` and the array is like the above, then one of the solutions would be to run operation **1** three times:

1. Before any moves:

```
{1,2,5,7,8,3}
```

2. After first move:

```
{2,2,5,7,8,3} // <-- `1` changed to `2`
```

3. After second move:

```
{3,2,5,7,8,3} // <-- `2` changed to `3`
```

4. After third move:

```
{3,3,5,7,8,3} // <-- `2` changed to `3`
```

So the resulting array would be:

```
{3,3,5,7,8,3}
```

---

Do you understand the problem now?

Comment: @Sebastian Kaczmarek, When out of two, one move needs to be taken ? Take either one move and calculate the number of similar elements with min moves, Is it ? And What  kind of code part gives assurity that calculated min number of moves are correct ?

Comment: Again, you are given an arbitrary array. And you are allowed to either increase the number that is currently smallest by one or decrease the number thats currently biggest by one. They give you a `k`, for example `4`. Now you can use the two operations to try to get 4 equal numbers. For example `[1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 3]`: increase, increase, increase, increase, increase, increase, increase, increase, increase. Now you have `[5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 5]` and thus 4 times a `5`. The number of operations needed for this were 9 (9x increase). Is it possible to achieve 4 times the same value with less operations?

Comment: @Sebastian Kaczmarek, Makes sense, But how would I know i need to pick which element or Integer I need to duplicate with min moves ? Becasue every element has its own possibilities to get duplicated wrt other elements in a array ? In big array, dont you think so we need to check all unique elements and their possibilites to get duplicated with min number of moves ?

Comment: That is a different question, namely how to solve the task. Your current question only asks what the task actually means. I would suggest you create a second question. But note that you are then required to show some attempts and explain in more detail what exactly is unclear to you, otherwise the question will be downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the algorithm to find `k` equal elements:

At any given step in the algorithm, there are some number of equal elements, say `j`. If `j >= k`, you're done. Otherwise, you need to choose some combination of the moves to increase `j`.

You don't have much flexibility in what you can do. You can only reduce a maximal element, or increase a minimal element.

Let's say there is a unique maximal element (i.e. when there is only one element in the array equal to the maximum element). You can increase `j` by (at least) 1 by reducing that until it equals the second-largest element.

Similarly, you can increase `j` by (at least) 1 by increasing a unique minimal element  (i.e. when there is only one element in the array equal to the maximum element) until it equals the second-smallest element.

Therefore, the smallest number of moves to achieve the (at least) 1 increase is the one out of [decrease the maximal; increase the maximal] which achieve this.

For example, in the array `[1, 3, 5, 6]`, your choices are:

- Take 2 moves to increase the 1 so it equals 3: `[3, 3, 5, 6]`
- Take 1 move to decrease the 6 so it equals 5: `[1, 3, 5, 5]`

In this case, you increase `j` by 2 most cheaply by decreasing the 6.

But after doing that, there are equal maximal elements: there are two elements equal to 5. By decreasing one of these, you *decrease* `j` by 2 (because `[1, 3, 4, 5]` has no equal elements); but by decreasing the maximum again, you make `j` the same as it was before (because `[1, 3, 4, 4]` again has 2 equal elements). So, you've got to do some work to "stand still" (that is, get `j` back to its previous value), before you can then decrease the maximum to increase `j`.

(Similarly for the minimal elements)

So, your algorithm can find the (greedy) minimum number of steps to make `j == k` by deciding whether to [decrease the maximal elements] or [increase the minimal element]. I don't know if the greedy minimum is actually the minimum, but I can't think of an obvious algorithm to find it non-greedily, other than searching all possibilities, which would have awful computational complexity, so is probably not what this interview was looking for.

Comment: Great answer, would benefit from concrete examples though.

Comment: @Zabuza but then I'd have to actually understand what I wrote... rolls eyes.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I'm not able to understand the importance of second last paragraph in your answer ? Why j needs to be alter once reached to required j value ?

Comment: @Maria you start with some number of equal elements in the array. You have to change the number of equal elements to reach some target value. Not sure how else to explain.